# MongoDB user with role userAdminAnyDatabase on admin database

Tags: mongodb, authentication, credentials

If I create a user in the admin DB of my MongoDB instance as follows:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "adminpassword",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

Then I create a DB named "test_db" on the same MongoDB instance.

Can I use the user "admin" to read write data on the db "test_db"?

Or do I need to create another user for that DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'd need another user, or to increase the privileges of the `userAdminAnyDatabase` user. `userAdminAnyDatabase` gives complete user admin powers, including the power to grant any role and privilege to any user. It does not give any read or write permissions on non-user data (though a user admin can grant themselves read and write privileges on any data).